# Is 'amenable' a derogatory description of a person?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, connotation

I'm asking someone for a reference letter, and almost used the word amenable. Looked it up, and definitely hesitated when the definition was "easily persuaded or controlled".

```
I would like to list you as a reference, if you are amenable to that.
```

I don't want to call a professional "easily persuaded or controlled". Call me crazy, but I thought that the connotation of the word was 'a pleasant person'. Any opinions here?

Comment: In this case, it is not a derogatory description; _to be amenable to `NP`_ is an idiom, common in requests for favors, as here; it means to agree with `NP`, at least temporarily. Similar to _if you're agreeable with that, if you will agree to do so, at your convenience,_ and a thousand other formulaic phrases with the same import.

Comment: Yeah, it basically mans "agreeable" in such a context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any negative connotations of *[amenable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/amenable)* would be connected to a **general** susceptibility to the control of others. In many **particular** situations, and even in some general situations, *amenability* is seen as an admirable trait of flexibility:

> adjective
>
> 1 Open and responsive to suggestion; easily persuaded or controlled:
>   *parents who have amenable children*
>
> 1.1 (amenable to) Capable of being acted upon in a particular way; susceptible:

The historical use of the *[amenable](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=amenable&allowed_in_frame=0)* is consistent with the negative connotations of intimidation:

> 1590s, "*liable*,"
>   from Anglo-French *amenable*, Middle French *amener*
>   "answerable" (to the law),
>   from *à* "to" (see ad-) + *mener* "to lead,"
>   from Latin *minare* "to drive (cattle) with shouts,"
>   variant of *minari*
>   "threaten" (see menace (n.)).
>   Sense of "tractable" is from 1803, from
>   notion of disposed to answer or submit to influence.

In the context of the OP, the predicative *amenable to that* suggests the positive particular disposition. But if we were concerned that a prospective reference is a control freak, who would be offended at the suggestion of *intimidation* in any situation, we could avoid all doubt by using the **synonym** *[agreeable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/agreeable)*:

> 2 [PREDICATIVE] Willing to agree to something:

*I would like to list you as a reference, if you are **agreeable** with that.*

Comment: +1, At times the "agreeability" here is even extended to apply to the circumstances directly, as in, 'that (the circumstances) would be amenable" and "the circumstances are amenable".